# Cancel url request to avoid multiple api calls

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a search text field on top of my `UITableView`. And when I type on the search field, an api gets called for search.

Now in this scenario, the api gets called for every character that’s typed. To avoid this and to have the api called just once for the entire term in the text field , I want to cancel the previous api requests.

This is the code I have for cancelling the request..but it’s not working..what has gone wrong..?

```
fileprivate func cancelRequest(_ url: URL) {
    cancelRequestsOfURLs([url.absoluteString])
  }



func cancelRequestsOfURLs (_ urlList: [String]) {
    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks in
      // Cancel Data Tasks
      dataTasks.forEach {
        for url in urlList {
          if ($0.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent == url) {
            print("Cancelling: \(String(describing: $0.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString))")
            $0.cancel()
          }
        }
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Here, each time, the control reaches the for-each part and exits out. It doesn't go inside.

**EDIT 1: Sequence of api call**

This is the sequence with which I'm making my api call...

```
1.WebServiceClient.shared.getGroupList(withParameters: param….

2.  func getGroupList(withParameters param…. {
    guard let url = APIClient.shared.createWebServiceUrl…..else {
      return
    }
    sendRequest(toURL: url,
                method: .post,
                …

3.   func sendRequest(toURL url :URL,
                   method: HTTPMethod,
                   ….-> Void) {

    let dataRequest = request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
    if let request = dataRequest.request {
      if (URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request) != nil) {
        URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: request)
      }
    }


    dataRequest.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    dataRequest.responseJSON() { [weak self] response in
      guard let `self` = self else  { return }
…
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than canceling all of your sessions API requests, maybe you just want to call the request which initiated from search.
Your example request:-

```
var request: Request?

// In your search method
request = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(path!, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: createHeader()).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        // Do something with response
    case .failure(let error) :
        // Do something with faliure
    }
}
```

Then you can just keep the reference to this request object and cancel it using

```
request?.cancel()
request = nil

// Call search api again
```

You can do this when you are calling next API for search.

Comment: ok @Aks. I have edited the question with the sequence of my api call. In that, in the 3rd point, `dataRequest` is the request and if I have to cancel it as you suggested, where should I do that..?

Comment: Your 3rd request is the one which you call for searching? If that's the case you can call the `cancel()` on `dataRequest` just before that.
You have to hold on to the `dataRequest` reference, in your VC.

Comment: true @Aks but the function `func sendRequest(toURL url ...` is a common function which is accessed by all apis. So cancelling the request will cancel all other api requests. Can I have a common function which does the job of just cancelling the requests like I have above for `sendRequest..` ?

Comment: I might suggest you this. add a new parameter to your function for checking if request is for search. If yes, add the "request" to an array. Next time you get a search request, cancel requests for old search using this array.

Comment: @asd2 You can return the `Request` object from `func sendRequest(toURL url ...` function and capture the object only where you are calling for `search`. Other places you can ignore the return value. This way you can use the existing code with minimum changes and still able to cancel.